# Minimum Number of piles

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Suppose we have N stones. They have the same size and weight, but they might have different strength.The $i$-th stone can hold at most $x_i$ stones on its top (we'll call xi the strength of the stone).

Suppose all the stones have the same size, **We cannot put more than one stone directly on the top of some stone.**

For example, imagine $3$ stones: the first has strength $2$, the second has strength $1$ and the third has strength $1$. We cannot put the second and the third stone simultaneously directly on the top of the first one. But we can put the second stone directly on the top of the first one, and then the third stone directly on the top of the second one. We will call such a construction of stones a *pile*.

Now we want to construct piles from all the stones. Each pile will contain some stones from top to bottom, and there cannot be more than $x_i$ stones on the top of $i$-th stone. What is the minimal number of piles we need to construct?

EXAMPLE : Let we have $5$ stones with strength $(0,1,2,3,4)$ then we can do it in one pile only.

Let if $N=3$ and their strengths be $(0,0,10)$ then we need to construct 2 piles for it.